# Parse Json in list view and add click listener to each list item

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, jsonparser

I am making a streaming application and I am trying to parse `JSON`  in a list view dynamically , the response I get is name, photo and URL, I can't pass the URL on video view , to be more specific I want so when you click on the list item it should play the URL on video view , and I am also struggling with the photo.

I succeeded by showing the `JSON` object names in a list view but I don't have idea how to pass the URL on the video view and the photo , this is my code

```
<pre>
 public class CamerasJSON{
        public String url;
        public String photo;
        public String name;
   }

  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "https://test.com/index.php";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
            CamerasJSON[] CamerasJSON = 
            gson.fromJson(jsonStr,CamerasJSON[].class);

            for(int i=0; i<CamerasJSON.length; i++){
                CamerasJSON cm = CamerasJSON[i];

                String name = cm.name;
                String photo = cm.photo;
                String streamUrl = cm.url;

                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                contact.put("name", name);
                contact.put("photo", photo);
                contact.put("streamUrl", streamUrl);

                contactList.add(contact);

                Log.e(TAG, "KONTAKT : " + contactList);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + CamerasJSON.length);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(FullscreenActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "name"},

                    new int[]{R.id.name});
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

How to add click listener to each of the list items so when you click on them it should play the URL to the video view

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use RecyclerView and RecyclerViewAdapter.

Comment: can you give me an example please, if it is not a problem